# Canvas pixel bleeding / accuracy issue

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, pixel

Running into what appear to be rounding errors when drawing tile data with canvas, just to illustrate the point boiled it down to the minimal reproducible example. Basically the draw call is using the source rectangle of (0, 0, 32, 32), which is the grid in the illustration. But Firefox grabs a sliver more, sampling past the source rectangle.

Top section is Firefox, bottom Section is Google Chrome
[image: Top is Firefox, bottom is Chrome]

Ideas?

Comment: try to create a reduced testcase that runs on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

- for pixel graphics you probably want to set [smoothing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.imageSmoothingEnabled) to `false`
- you should make sure you're not passing non-integer values to any of the canvas methods
- if you're not displaying the canvas element at its native size (i.e. due to CSS resizing) then you also want to set the CSS property [image-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) to `crisp-edges`.

Comment: - `imageSmoothingEnabled` is set to false, all the prefix versions are covered. Everything is being clamped to integer values and canvas to window size is mapped 1:1